# How to add a click event to any of my markers which i have stored in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, leaflet, markers

I'm working with leaflet js and I have an array in which i store my markers which are automatically added to the map after the location of the user has been obtained.
**problem is that i want to add an onclick listener so that any marker that is clicked will run a function.**
please help me out cuz i'm stuck right now.

```js
//objects for markers
var allMarkers=[];
var  AllMarkers = L.layerGroup(allMarkers);

var Allpoints=[{
    "latitudes":9.4258946,"longitudes":-0.8842213,              "names":"first", "eastings":556568, "northings":446445, "description": "aijaskj jnrkajra skjanjanek ", "elevations": 5668

},

    {
        "latitudes":9.4254946,"longitudes":-0.8812213,  "names":"second"},

        {
            "latitudes":9.4054946,"longitudes":-0.8802213,  "names":"third"},

            {
                "latitudes":9.4754946,"longitudes":-0.8712213,  "names":"fourth"},
        
    ];


//automatically plot all previous markers
var point = L.point(9.2754946, -0.8912213);
q = 0;
while(q< Allpoints.length){
    //create Marker here
    _newMarker = L.marker(
        
        [Allpoints[q].latitudes, Allpoints[q].longitudes], 

        {title: Allpoints[q].names,
            riseOnHover: true,           

        }  ).addTo(mymap);

    allMarkers.push(_newMarker);
    q++
}

//function to send back the details of the clicked marker to a paragraph in my index.htm


//PROBLEM
L.marker('click', markers, showMarkerDetails)   //however the code immediately above does not work

function showMarkerDetails(){
    $("#returnControlName").html(controlName);
    $("#returnControlLocation").html(`${controlLat.toFixed(4)} ,  ${controlLong.toFixed(4)} `);
    $("#returnControlEastings").html(controlEastings);
     $("#returnControlName").html(controlNorthings);
     $("#returnControlName").html(controlElevation);
     $("#returnControlName").html(controlDescription); 
}
```

Comment: what can I do if I want to add events to markers?

Answer (score 0):

With `L.marker()` you add new markers / points to the map, you can't add events like that to them. (`L.marker('click', markers, showMarkerDetails)` )

Change your code to:

```
//automatically plot all previous markers
var point = L.point(9.2754946, -0.8912213);
q = 0;
while(q< Allpoints.length){
    //create Marker here
    _newMarker = L.marker([Allpoints[q].latitudes, Allpoints[q].longitudes], 
        {title: Allpoints[q].names,
            riseOnHover: true,           

        }).addTo(mymap);
    _newMarker.informations = Allpoints[q]; // save the data to the marker to read it later out
    _newMarker.on('click',showMarkerDetails); // add click event to the markers
    allMarkers.push(_newMarker);
    q++
}

function showMarkerDetails(e){
    var layer = e.target // get the clicked marker
    var infos = layer.informations;
    console.log(infos.description);


    $("#returnControlName").html(controlName);
    $("#returnControlLocation").html(`${controlLat.toFixed(4)} ,  ${controlLong.toFixed(4)} `);
    $("#returnControlEastings").html(controlEastings);
     $("#returnControlName").html(controlNorthings);
     $("#returnControlName").html(controlElevation);
     $("#returnControlName").html(controlDescription); 
}
```

Comment: with `.on(event, function)` you can add events to layers. In your case this is `_newMarker.on('click',showMarkerDetails);` [Marker Events](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#marker-move)